# Loading a dll in Java For Windows XP

Tags: java

I'm attempting to load a dll using the `System.loadLibrary("myDllFile")` that I built on a linux machine using Makefile.  I get a

> *java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError c:\test\myDllFile.dll: can't load this .dll (machine code=0x101) on a IA 32-bit platform*

exception when I run the main java class containing the `loadLibrary` statement. I'm attempting to run the java class on Windows XP.  Do I need a separate dll for windows xp (32bit) and windows 7 (64 bit)?

Comment: Yes, Win32 .dll's are incompatible with Windows/64-bit .dll's.  Linux shared libraries similarly have incompatible elf-32 and elf-64 formats.  And none of these four, mutually exclusive binary formats are typically used with Java.  Unless you're using JNI.

Comment: so I would have to create the dlls on a 32 bit machine or is there a makefile option to do that?

Comment: That would depend on who wrote your Makefile, and how you're compiling it. Sometimes Linux can “fool” the Makefile with `setarch i686 make`; but that's extremely project-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. You'll have to port the native code to run on each OS, and link it separately.

However, if you actually have a `.dll`, and not a `.so`, it sounds like you may have cross-compiled for Win64, when you meant to do so for Win32. (Perhaps using MinGW?) If you have such a cross-compiler set-up, you should be able to specify building for Win32 vs. Win64. Alternatively, you can tell your 64-bit Linux system to pretend to be 32-bit using `setarch i686`, if your Makefile happens to be ill-behaving.

If you have a Linux `.so`, it'll require quite a bit more work to port to Windows…